# SICP ex4.12 about share and call-by-value

Tags: scheme, sicp

```
(define (make-frame var val)
  (cons var val))
(define (frame-variables frame) (car frame))
(define (frame-values frame) (cdr frame))
(define (add-binding-to-frame! var val frame)
  (set-car! frame (cons var (car frame)))
  (set-cdr! frame (cons val (cdr frame))))
(define (empty-env? env)
  (null? env))
(define (env-variables env)
 (define (merge x)
      (if (null? x)
    '()
    (append (car x) (merge (cdr x)))))
 (merge (map frame-variables env)))
(define (env-values env)
    (define (merge x)
      (if (null? x)
        '()
        (append (car x) (merge (cdr x)))))
    (merge (map frame-values env)))
(define (enclosing-environment env) (cdr env))
(define (first-frame env) (car env))
(define the-empty-environment '())
(define (lookup-variable-value var env)
(define (lookup variables values)
    (if (null? variables)
      (error "Unbound variable" var)
      (if (eq? var (car variables))
        (car values)
        (lookup (cdr variables) (cdr values)))))
  (lookup (env-variables env) (env-values env)))
(define (set-variable-value! var val env)
  (define (lookup-set! variables vals)
    (if (null? variables)
      (error "Sorry Unbound variable -- SET!" var)
      (if (eq? var (car variables))
        (set-car! vals val)
        (lookup-set! (cdr variables) (cdr vals)))))
  (lookup-set! (env-variables env) (env-values env))
  'ok)
(define test-env 
    (list (cons (list 'x 'y 'z) (list 1 2 3)) 
          (cons (list 'a 'b 'c) (list 4 5 6)) 
          (cons (list 'm 'n 'q) (list 7 8 9))))
```

The `lookup` procedure works well, but the `set` procedure can't change the val of the var.So here we are.

Scheme is call-by-value, so i doubt that the return value of `merge` doesn't share object with `env`. But i don't understand why it don't share.

`append` shares,`map` shares,`cons` shares,(i mean `(define y (cons x x))` then you `(set-car! x ...)` the `y` will also change) but why doesn't a defined function share?

So i just want to get all of the vars and vals of `env` (i mean strip off the frame),then search or set them. But i stuck here.

```
(define x '(a b c))
(define (y z) (set-car! z 'change))
(y x) => (change b c)
```

This works,so it means the `z` is replaced by a pointer to `x` or the return value of `merge` is a copy of the "old",identical but independent?

When the formal parameter of `merge`(or others) is replaced by a list,is it a pointer to the list?

How does call-by-value works here?

How can I achieve my idea?

Answer (score 0):

You use `env-values` and `env-variables` which effectively appends the frames together into one list. *It does this by copying each element to a new list*. Your `set-car!` alters a cons in that new list and does not change the original `env`.

You should make lookup iterate the original frames and variables and perhaps return the pair which holds the value. If not found you throw an error like `(error "Unbound variable" var)`.

That way `lookup-variable-value` would become

```
(define (lookup-variable-value var env)
  (car (lookup var env)))
```

And `set-variable-value!` would become:

```
(define (set-variable-value! var val env)
  (set-car! (lookup var env) val))
```

Comment: Sorry,it doesn't work,the lookup in your solutions is different from mine,but i change mine based on your opinion, still doesn't work. And the append in the merge didn't creat

Comment: @S.Tian To be sure you implemented `lookup` correct this expression should be `#t`: `(let ((env '(((x) . (v))))) (eq? (lookup 'x env) (cdar env)))`

Comment: Sorry for my ugly comment, I have worked it out, Anyway, Thank you so much!